# https and without http opens different websites

Tags: http, https

I am totally clueless on this. My website www.sociomarker.com has 2 different websites opening, when using https and http.

**Following are the screenshots:**

http://www.sociomarker.com/

[image]

https://www.sociomarker.com/

[image]

This is really weird.

PS: I am not on drugs..

Answer (score 0):

hi could you tell me r u using shared hosting...... if you are using shared hosting then for using https you have to take dedicated Ip then only you can  use https.Your ssl certificate is on zealwebtechnologies ...thats why you are getting that result and this will make your seo down

Comment: i dont want to use https; but how can someone show some other website on my domain with use of https. I got an answer here http://superuser.com/questions/792202/different-website-at-https-then-at-http I probably will redirect https to http. Just a thought though.

Comment: hi u r using shared hosting and parent of that is zealwebtechnologies site . if they assign other domain same thing will be happend to that domain too. they have to make zealweb to a slave

Comment: finally resolved.. the hosting provider solved it on giving an warning of discontinuing with their company. :)

Comment: i already told you .. You are using shared hosting .. and https is on zealteachnology and that is parent one....and your site is slave of that. please marked it as an answer @Utpal-UrBestPal